# VS Code: What is the difference between push and publish

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

On the GIT tab in Visual Studio Code there is an context menu with these items:

- Sync
- Pull
- Pull (release)
- Push

==================

- Publish

==================

...

What does the publish button do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After checking the source code of Visual Studio Code.

## Push

Push the **current** branch to the **default** remote **upstream**

```
public run(context?: any):Promise {
    return this.gitService.push() // ... removed for brevity        
}
```

#### Active when:

There is **UPSTREAM** and recent push/pulls (ahead)

```
if (!HEAD || !HEAD.name || !HEAD.upstream) {
    return false;
}

if (!HEAD.ahead) { // no commits to pull or push
    return false;
}
```

### Publish

Allows you to choose which remote you want to push to.

```
public run(context?: any):Promise {
        const model = this.gitService.getModel();
        const remotes = model.getRemotes();
        const branchName = model.getHEAD().name;
        let promise: TPromise<string>;

        if (remotes.length === 1) {
            const remoteName = remotes[0].name;
            promise = TPromise.as(result ? remoteName : null);
        } else {
            // open the option picker            
            promise = this.quickOpenService.pick(picks, { placeHolder })
                .then(pick => pick && pick.label);
        }

        return promise
            .then(remote => remote && this.gitService.push(remote, branchName, { setUpstream: true }))            
}
```

#### Active when

There is **NO UPSTREAM** and off course remote branches are set.

```
if (model.getRemotes().length === 0) {
    return false;
}

if (!HEAD || !HEAD.name || HEAD.upstream) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol):

> If there is no upstream branch configured and the Git repository has remotes set up, the Publish action is enabled. This will let you publish the current branch to a remote.

So I'd expect that if you have an upstream branch configured, you would be able to **Push** (i.e. push directly to the configured upstream branch) and if you have no upstream branch configured you are only allowed to **Publish** (i.e. select a remote and branch to push at).

Answer (score 9):

**Publish** will push the branch to the remote AND set up the local branch to track the remote branch.

**Push** just pushes and doesn't set upstream tracking information (ie: `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` configuration).

When there is no upstream branch, and `push.default = simple` (the git default), **Push** will raise a dialog to suggest a publish.

Answer (score 1):

Push = git push ...

Publish = git push -u ...